# Relations retrieval difference in Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationships

Whats the difference between

```
$this->translations;
```

and

```
$this->translations()->get();
```

where translations is the relationship of the current model. I thought both do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are basically the same thing.

However:

- `$this->translations()->get();` will query the database every time this is called.
- `$this->translations;` will execute the database query the first time and will store the result in memory for later use.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->translations;` will return all the translations to the relating model, 
whereas `$this->translations()` will give you query builder instance where you can add your constraints to the relating model e.g

```
$this->translations()->where(['locale' , 'en'])->orderBy('sort')->get();
```